# If text contains "Quartal" or "Year" then do something - google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am working on a google docs sheet, currently trying to automate most of the data entry. I want to do an action if a text is found in a cell.

Have a look at this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlfftUoJOAjCdGp0Z2stbmhncGs0bFE5ZU43dkFLVEE#gid=0

**I have those scenarios:**

1. Monthly -> Indicated by number. Pseudo-code: if number.
2. Quarterly -> Indicated by "Quarter". Pseudo-code: if text contains "Quarter"
3. Yearly -> Indicated by "Yearly". Pseudo-code: if text contains "Yearly"

How can I check each of the three scenarios in Google docs?

Comment: I did not understood what is your problem. Can you please edit your question and re-phrase it? By the way, formulas can be copied down and they will update the references accordingly, do you know that?

Comment: Thx + sorry. I tried to made it more clear. does it help?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's me, but it didn't. I saw now that you question does not have the google-apps-script tag, I'll re-tag it and someone else will probably be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function foo(){
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your_spreadsheet_id").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A:A");
var values = range.getValues();
for(var i in values){
  if(values[i][0].match("Monthly")!=null){
     //cell contains "Monthly". Do something 
  } 
  if(values[i][0].match("Quarterly")!=null){
     //cell contains "Quarterly". Do something 
  }
  if(values[i][0].match("Yearly")!=null){
     //cell contains "Yearly". Do something 
  }
}
```

This will scan all the cells in the A column and call different functions based on their content.